# Multiple ROOT accounts on system

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I have about three ROOT accounts on my system, I have no idea how this happened but I have been messing with useradd and userdel, so maybe the two accounts I removed were replaced with a root account.

My question is, how would I delete the other root accounts?

When I type userder -r root, it says no user exists

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no such command as `userder`

Comment: You could try this. Untested. `cat /etc/passwd | grep root`

That should output one line: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Do you have more than that one line?

Comment: When you say multiple root accounts, do you mean there are multiple accounts in /etc/passwd named root, or do you mean there are multiple accounts with a UID of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Each account on a system has a number assigned to it.  You may see these user id numbers with the `id` command, without becoming a privileged user or those user accounts.

```
vagrant@host:~$ id
uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),118(sambashare)
vagrant@host:~$ id ntp
uid=105(ntp) gid=110(ntp) groups=110(ntp)
vagrant@host:~$ id pulse
uid=109(pulse) gid=119(pulse) groups=119(pulse),29(audio)
vagrant@host:~$ id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
vagrant@host:~$ for ACCOUNT in root ntp pulse ; do id $ACCOUNT; done 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
uid=105(ntp) gid=110(ntp) groups=110(ntp)
uid=109(pulse) gid=119(pulse) groups=119(pulse),29(audio)
vagrant@host:~$
```

As @Trevor mentioned in the comments, you can (without being the root account) grep through the `/etc/password` file for a list of accounts that have the word *root* in the name.  I would do `grep -i root /etc/passwd` for a case-insensitive search.  The `id` command can help identify the user IDs attached to each name.

I suspect that there may be account names like `'root '`  and `' root '` created (note the spaces between the apostrophes) but these will not have UID zero.  The `id` command should help identify the user ID values and user names; the parentheses around the name should help provide a clear argument to `userdel` so you are able to remove unneeded accounts.